# Understading the $L_p$ and $l_p$ norms of a function $f$ defined on a finite set $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

I have come across a question:

> Let $f$ be a complex function on a finite set $X$, i.e. $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Let $1\leq p \leq q \leq \infty$. Show that $||f||_{L_p}\leq ||f||_{L_q}$ and $||f||_{l_p}\geq ||f||_{l_q}$.

I am really confused by the meaning of the $L_p$ norm on a function defined on a finite set. I think the $l_p$ norm is simply:

$||f||_{l_p} = (\Sigma_{x\in X} f(x)^p )^{1/p}$

but cannot think of what the $L_p$ norm could be. Wikipedia uses an integral, but since $X$ is finite would this not just reduce to the sum above?

Background: in case this is relevant, this question comes from a course on fourier methods in combinatorics.

Comment: For the $L^p$-norm you need some measure on your set,  and for the required inequality, it should be a probability measure.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for your reply! I would think the probability measure would be the uniform one, but in any case I would the integral over finite set with uniform probability measure not just reduce to the sum?

Comment: I. E. $\int_X |f(x) |^p d\mu (x) $